# How do I change the icon of a button in livecode, using code and not the inspector tool?

Tags: button, live, livecode

I want to have a button change appearance when certain events occur. I thought the code would look something like this:

```
on mouseUp
   set the icon of this button to the id 1044
end mouseUp
```

The icon of the button is its normal appearance and in inspector when you put the id of a certain image into the icon space the image will take on the appearance of whatever has that icon. What code would allow me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set the icon of button "abc" to 1044
```

or

```
set the icon of button "abc" to the id of image "source image"
```

In both cases you are setting the icon property of the button to the id of an image object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the icon by referring to the name of the desired image. Say you have a button named "foo" and an image named "bar":

```
set the icon of button "foo" to "bar"
```

Comment: You can indeed use an image name when assigning an icon.  However, the id of the image is what actually gets assigned to the button's icon property, so when querying the icon property, you'll get the id of the image, not the image's name.